# Xamarin installation

Tags: xamarin, installation

We watched a Xamarin installation video by Jason D, downloaded XamarinInstaller.exe version3.6 and ran it. We noticed that unlike the video, we are only seeing the Andriod SDK and the Xamarin for Visual Studio components in our options and missing the GTK# and Xamarin Studio. The install finished successfully so we don't know whether we have everything we need or not.

The reason we think this is because when we launch VS, we don't see any Xamarin.Forms type projects, for example.

Can someone tell us if we may be missing some pieces?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio 2013 or 2015?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Remove all
2.- instal VisualStudio 2015
3.- run xamarin installer

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the extension correctly that binds xamarin with visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Open **Control Panel > Programs**, search for your edition of Visual Studio and then click the **Change/Uninstall** button at the top of the window. Wait for a moment while the Visual Studio Installer launches, and then repair the installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** I have followed the below steps for Visual studio 2015. Hope that it will work for other versions of Visual studio.

To install Xamarin framework into Visual studio successfully, please follow the below steps,

**Visual studio 2015 community edition installation:**

 To download VS2015 Community edition ISO (Size is around 7GB), check 
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/07/download-visualstudio-2015.html

To install VS2015 Community edition, please follow the below link, http://www.howtosolutions.net/2015/08/solving-installation-is-stuck-problem-in-visual-studio-community-edition/

Offline installation would be more faster (around 1 to 2 hours).
If any further issue comes, repair MS Visual C++ 2015 redistributable.
Finally, VS 2015 will be installed quickly.

**Xamarin framework Installation:**

 To download Xamarin, visit https://www.xamarin.com/download

 You can download Xamarin Installer.

Launch Xamarin installer, it will download and install the below components,

1. Java 8.
2. Android SDK, NDK and emulator images.
3. Xamarin Framework.

To store the setup of components, launch Xamarin installer and while it starts downloading, disconnect internet. 
It will abort and open Manual installation instructions. Connect to internet again and you can save setup.exe for all components from manual wizard and install it for later purpose.

After Xamarin is installed, launch Visual studio 2015. 
You can create Xamarin projects, under Visual C# -> Cross platform option.

Revert back for queries, if any.